# override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a question regarding `override func prepare for segue`. I have a table view controller that has a `UINavigationController` and a button from another view controller that connects to the UINav as a "present modally" with identifier as "fakeButtonPressed".

My question is that when I add this code into my view controller for when the button is pressed, it throws an error:

> "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9c784018f0"

in console. Not sure why it's not working.

Trying to get to AddPlayerViewController > UINavigationController > AddPlayerTableViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "fakeButtonPressed"{
        let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! AddPlayerTableViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the complete error as well as point out the line causing it.

Comment: @Dustin Lee Do you mean you present to a  `tableViewController ` which embed in a  `nav controller` ?

Comment: Yes! thats what I was trying to do, i instead just placed a uiviewcontainer in a view controller and embeded a uitable in that view controller instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls, Remove your Button click Action Preference in your story board.

To remove the Action event pls, click on cross Button in Touch Up Inside event as seen on above image, It will solve your problem.

Yes, you can also write prepare for segue method like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "fakeButtonPressed"
    {
        let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! AddPlayerTableViewController
        controller.str = "Done..."
    }
}
```

**Or**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "fakeButtonPressed"
    {
        let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! AddPlayerTableViewController
        controller.str = "Done..."
    }
}
```